# Overriding paintComponent

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, mouselistener

Ok so I have been trying to figure this out for the past 26 hours with guide and online help but no success.

All I want to do is draw an oval when the user clicks in the PaintPanel
Please someone help so I can sleep :P

[image: screen]

In PaintApplet class:

```
  private void PaintPanelMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if(FillRadioButton.isSelected())
    {
    PaintPanel.setBackground(JColor.getColor());
   PaintPanel.repaint();
    }
    if(BrushRadioButton.isSelected())
    {
         Point ComponentPoint = PaintPanel.getLocationOnScreen();
         PaintPanel.add(new Painter(ComponentPoint));
    }
}
```

Painter Class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import java.awt.*;

public class Painter extends JPanel{

Point  Component;

public Painter(Point Com)
{
    Component = Com;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{

        super.paint(g);
      Point CursorPoint=   MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation(); //gets cursorpoint

       int ComPX =  Component.x;
        int ComPY =  Component.y;
        int CurPX =  CursorPoint.x;
        int CurPY =  CursorPoint.y;
        int FinalX = CurPX - ComPX;
        int FinalY =  CurPY - ComPY;

       g.drawOval(FinalX, FinalY, 20, 20);




}
}
```

Comment: Please respect Java naming conventions. Your code is very hard to read.

Comment: By looking at your code, I think you need to cast Graphics g to Graphics2D

Comment: Also, tell us what you expect this code to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: It does nothing. I want when I click on the paint panel to draw an oval

Comment: Unrelated, but I love how Photoshop is right next to μTorrent in your taskbar.

Answer (score 4):

Don't call

```
super.paint(g);
```

within `paintComponent`. This will result in an infinite loop in the paint chain mechanism. Instead you need

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

For better help sooner consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)