# JFrame text displaying wrong

Tags: java, swing, text, fonts, jframe

I am creating an app that uses an undecorated border and wanted to add a shadow to the my JFrame. I got the shadow working but in the process the text got all screwed up.

Due to the size of the program I can not post all of my code but the problem does go away when I remove this line.
        setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
So what could cause the text to display blurry and incorrectly? It is bolder and some of the letters seem to be taller.
And I cannot post a picture since I do not have a level 10 reputation. 
Here is more of my code:

```
    int extendBy=30;
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width + extendBy, height + extendBy));
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width + extendBy, height + extendBy));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width + extendBy, height + extendBy));
setUndecorated(true);

setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));   // all hell breaks loose here
setContentPane(new ShadowPane());
getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setLayout(null);   // I know setting null this is bad practice
```

edit: acquired 10 reputation so here is a pic (look at W or A or k): [image: textPic]

Comment: here you have your 10 reputation, now post a picture :)

Comment: `Due to the size of the program I can not post all of my code` - Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: What sort of sorcery do you have Matthias? seriously tho how did you do that

Comment: This is likely an issue either with per-pixel alphering process or the fact that you've used font or antistaling rendering hints somewhere in the paint process

Comment: @rezen__ I just did an upvote to your question which gives you 5 reputation. 5 you had already, that makes 10. As the question is nicely asked (though it is still a bit lacking in details) an upvote is well deserved. And as the picture is showing your problem, you already got a rather helping comment by MadProgrammer who is a pro around Swing / UI stuff.

Comment: `setLayout(null);   // I know setting null this is bad practice`  So why do it?  *Especially* in code that is obviously broken?  BTW - Stairway to Heaven is by Led Zeppelin, while Knocking on Heaven's door is by Bob Dylan & performed by a bunch of people, including Eric Clapton & Guns'n'Roses..  I'm also pretty sure Louei Louie is by a bunch of bands, none of which are The Kinks.  The person that compiled the list seems a bit confused about who performed what.  They have great taste in music though.  ;)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson  :( I know. I tried changing the track name by altering the file path but that did not change the id3 tags. and I did not know that about "louie louie". and thanks MadProgrammer... I will try solving the problem and posting the solution/tip for someone else

Comment: If you cannot get it fixed with the advice of @MadProgrammer, I recommend you post an SSCCE as advised by camickr.

Comment: What platform and what JRE brand and version is this? Can you reproduce the issue on other software? This looks a bit like a bug in the font rendering libraries, so I wouldn't be surprised if other people would see this differently on their systems. Nailing down which aspect of your system triggers this would help. By the way, any particular reason *why* you'd want transparent cells?

Comment: I know you're not going to like my suggestion, but I would build a functional app using completely standard Swing components first.  Then, when I had a working application. I might look into making the app a bit prettier.  Working > pretty.

Answer (score 1):

Try to override the paintComponent method for this JTable.

How to do it: [Overriding paintComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602235/overriding-paintcomponent)

For Your case i would use anti-aliasing to get rid of those unwanted effects.

```
jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable(){
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON );
        }
    };
```